# Can miners read the restricted data on our Smart Contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, security

I'm thinking to store around half a dozen private keys on a smart contract. The function to read private keys is restricted to owner (deployer) of the smart contract.

Do miners have access to the restricted data? If yes - Is there any way to protect our data on ethereum blockchain?

Comment: There is no restricted data in Ethereum blockchain. `private` variables are still accessible to anyone, they just don't produce a getter. Anything you want to keep private needs to be encrypted before placing on the blockchain and then decrypted after you read it from the blockchain.
TLDR - DON'T place raw private keys on the blockchain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ethereum blockchain doesn't secure the data on the smart contract. so putting private keys or any kind of sensitive data on a smart contract is not good and "technically illegal".

You need to **encrypt** the data you insert in your smart contract and **decrypt** it when reading it form your smart contract. (this should probably be done off-chain )

**=> All nodes with fully synchronized blockchain can see the data on your smart contract.**